# How to check value in (subrequest)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to check if the `idPartie` is in the subrequest. My subrequest shows that table
[image]

This is what I have tried

```
select * 
from partie 
where idPartie in (select dbo.gagnant(idPartie) as idJoueur, idPartie 
                   from Participer_Partie 
                   group by idPartie);
```

Comment: please improve the question,question at its current state is not quite answerable..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Why are you returning two columns from your subquery ? It won't work! Return only one column which you want to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right you return 2 columns from the subquery and make an "in"-comparison for idPartie. This will not work. Instead try something like this.

```
select * from partie
where idPartie in 
(select  distinct idPartie from Participer_Partie);
```